# Is it Safe to Compare Subscription-Expiration-Date & Current-Date on the Client Side? Or can this be manipulated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, websecurity, secure-coding

I get some data back from the backend, which tells me the expiration date of the user subscription. If this date is in the past, I navigate the user somewhere else, so she can't log in:

```
  if (expirationDate.getTime() < new Date().getTime()) {
      navigate('/subscription-expired')
  }
```

I am wondering whether it's safe to do a check like this comparison on the client? Can this be manipulated?

Comment: "Safe" has various definitions and aspects. Anything in the client side can be manipulated, so if this is your **only** check, you're in trouble. If you're checking this *also* on the server-side in critical spots, you're probably fine.

Comment: Safe? Dunno. Reliable? No.

Comment: @RobG Thanks a lot. Why would it not be reliable, can you expand?

Comment: @userjmillohara try imagining what happens if someone opens that page with JavaScript disabled, they'd be able to stay on it as long as they wanted.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts oh, so true! But then the rest of the page / the app that I am providing access to wouldn't work either, since it's all javascript. Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: `Date.prototype.getTime()` can also be manipulated to return whatever the user wants, either by setting the system clock or by running a script to overwrite the method with a user-defined function of their choosing. As people have already pointed out, this check should ideally be performed server-side when the page is being loaded with an HTTP request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Benefits** of checking data, validating data and other stuff on the **Client side** is:

- to alert a *regular user* that he/she is not on a good path (user informed of her subscription expiration). (result: user experience)
- reduce The server Load. when preventing The regular Users from sending invalid data to server. (regular users wont send additional data to server when they found out their subscription has been expired) (result: resource saving and performance)

but checking on the **Server side** is an **Obligation**, since there are *non-regular users* (whos modifies Js, posting data with Postman, bots, intruders ) which may send Http requests without intervention and validation of your client-side code could abuse your system.

> **Client side is the battle field of enemy**

### To summarize:

you **have to** validate data on **server side** in order to prevent any abusing.

but its **recommended to** validate data on the **client side** *too* to improve performance of the whole system.

for example in your case:

- on server-side :

  - check for expiration-time =>
  - if it has been expired =>
  - return 403 error with: `{message:"expired"}`
- on client-side :

  - if it got 403 error with `{message:"expired"}`. =>
  - redirect user.

Answer (score 1):

Could your users manipulate the JavaScript code or just have a wrong date and time on their computers? Sure they could. Would it be that critical? In your case you just want to redirect the user to another page, so it wouldn't be critical, but it would affect the trust in your application since it would behave in an unexpected way in some cases, and say the subscription is expired when it's not (or say it's not expired when it is).

It could be much more critical if you had a backend that trusted the client to provide the current date without verifying it because your data could be faked and your business rules could be bypassed.

It depends on the use case, but generally, you should not consider `new Date()` in the browser as a source of truth. Your backend remains the truth holder.

Answer (score 1):

You should NEVER trust anything on the client.

On top of that, **more importantly**, the server time, and your client time **could be different.**

So come to the question, is your subscription start time base on client or server time? (which should be server time, since we shouldn't trust client)

The safest way is for your server to return whether the subscription is valid aka true/false;

> If it's false, navigate('/subscription-expired')

On top of that, every page should contain the same check.